# Cannot un-ignore a tag

Tags: support, tags

I tried to remove *ds.algorithms* from my ignored tags by clicking on the popup "Remove ds.algorithms from Ignored Tags" link on the [ds.algorithms page](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ds.algorithms), and it didn't seem to work. Is this a bug? Is this my fault for using Google Chrome for OS X (version 7.0.517.41)? (It also doesn't work in Safari 5.0.2.)

I eventually figured out how to remove the tags by clicking on the X next to the tag on the list on the homepage.

Comment: Also, is this even the right place to ask this question? Both http://meta.stackexchange.com/ and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ seemed not like the right place...

Comment: meta.stackexchange.com is for Stack Exchange 1.0 and unrelated to us (so confusing).  meta.stackoverflow.com is the right place to report a bug on the Stack Exchange 2.0 engine we are using.  But the developers seem to be checking other meta sites, so posting it here should not be off the mark.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, click the [x] next to the tag anywhere you see the Ignored and Interesting panel.

Comment: I am glad that there is a solution for removing tags, but it still seems like a bug that clicking on the link labeled "Remove X from Interesting Tags" on the tag's page fails to do so.

Comment: This seems to be fixed for real now; thanks!